# Converting arguments to composite type

Tags: julia

I'm still getting acquainted with the way Julia works and I have an encountered an odd error that I have been unable to surmount:

I have a composite type declared as follows

```
type Mesh
    domain::Tuple
    resolution::Tuple
    stepsize::Tuple
    data::Array{TransferFunction, 2}
```

where a TransferFunction is another composite type that I have defined.

When I try and create an instance of this type (with an empty TransferFunction array) using a constructor,

```
my_mesh = Mesh((100, 100), (100,100), (1, 1), Array(TransferFunction, 2))
```

I get the following error message:

```
ERROR: `convert` has no method matching convert(::Type{Array{TransferFunction,2}}, ::Array{TransferFunction,1})
```

I'm not sure where the Array(TransferFunction, 1) is coming from. I'm assuming that this is a simple problem with a simple solution, but after delving through the Julia docs, I have been unable to find why this is error message is happening.

Anyone have any ideas?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`Array(TransferFunction, 2)` doesn't create a two-dimensional matrix — it's a 2-element vector.  But `Array{TransferFunction, 2}` is the type of a two-dimensional matrix of arbitrary size.  Which do you intend?

You can either change `Array(TransferFunction, 2)` to `Array(TransferFunction, 2, 1)` if you really want a matrix of transfer functions, or you can change the type declaration from a Matrix to a Vector: `Array{TransferFunction, 1}`.  It's a little confusion that the Array constructor arguments and type parameters look so similar, but mean very different things.

One way to help avoid this confusion is to use the `Matrix` or `Vector` typealiases in your declarations, e.g., `Vector{TransferFunction}` instead of `Array{TransferFunction, 1}`.

Comment: Perfect! Thanks for the help. From the definition of `Array()` [here](http://julia.readthedocs.org/en/latest/manual/arrays/), I was under the impression that `Array(TransferFunction, 2)` created a two-dimensional matrix of transfer functions. Thanks for clarifying!